# How to exclude Test.java classes in jar file

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, build, jar

I have developed a couple of utility classes including

```
FileHelper.java
Helper.java
```

and corresponding test classes

```
FileHelperTest.java
HelperTest.java
```

I can compile, install, and deploy the project without any issue.

[image]

So far so good. The problem appears when I include this jar file in another project's pom file to use my utility classes

[image]  [image]

and the test class also appears in intelliscence, which of course is not a very good approach.

I have tried pretty much all available solutions to exclude the test classes to jar file but all solutions are helping to skip the unit test execution during the build process not blocking test classes to be a part of jar file.

I tried different plugins:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/FileHelperTest.java*</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/HelperTest.java*</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/FileHelperTest*</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/HelperTest*</exclude>
                    </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

and a couple of more but .m2 files always contains.

[image]

Hope I have explained my problem in detail and wish you had already stumbled upon this issue and had solved it successfully, thanks in advance.

Comment: Testclasses Must be in *src/test/java*. Then they will not packaged in the jar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Your project is a maven project then Generally we keep the test classes in "src/test/java" package structure and maven does not package test classes in the jar.
So If not explicitly stated maven does not package the compiled test classes in the packaged jar.

Answer (score 0):

> If you absolutely must, you can also use the maven.test.skip property to skip compiling the tests. maven.test.skip is honored by Surefire, Failsafe and the Compiler Plugin.
>
> `mvn install -Dmaven.test.skip=true`

According to the [document](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/skipping-tests.html)